# Facebook API Check Rate Limit Usage /w Koala Gem

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

I'm using the [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) gem to connect to the Graph API. What I would like to know is how I can check my API usage against the rate limit using the gem. The gem doesn't seem to expose request headers in a way that would allow me to see if I am approaching my rate limit. I've also checked the API docs and can't find any information on how to check my usage programmatically, such as calling an endpoint to get usage data.

It looks like someone already forked the gem ([link to issue report](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/issues/522)) for this purpose already ([link to fork](https://github.com/Shopify/koala/commit/266ff05680f4a6393da55175dcdac8159d67b4bd)), but they don't provide a working example in code of how to pull the headers from a response and I have been unable to get it working myself.

For example, if I use the Shopify fork and try the following code, it returns an error:

```
[10] pry(main)> client = current_user.facebook_client
=> #<Koala::Facebook::API:0x007f84f94fbb60
 @access_token="SOMETHING",
 @app_secret="SECRET">
[11] pry(main)> resp = client.search('pokemon', type: :page)
=> [{"name"=>"Pokémon", "id"=>"230809307041021"},
 {"name"=>"Pokemon-Go", "id"=>"661667727331478"},...]
[12] pry(main)> resp.headers
NoMethodError: undefined method `headers' for #<Koala::Facebook::API::GraphCollection:0x007f84fb878ea8>
from (pry):12:in `__pry__'
```

I've also tried calling `client.headers`, which returns valid `headers` data, but the data includes nothing about my usage.

Comment: The usage header is only included when you get close to the rate limit

Comment: How close must I be to see the header? I'm trying to make my api calls adaptive so as to maximize the number of results a user can see when the usage is low while restricting usage when approaching the limit.

Comment: No idea how close you need to be

Comment: As a note, `resp.headers` should work from koala 3.0 after this merged https://github.com/arsduo/koala/pull/589